# Reusing the Data without hitting DB - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Am modifying the complex function which is already written where they are using the below code :

```
private List<string> Values()
{
    if (ViewBag.Sample == null)
    {
        ViewBag.Sample = TestData();
    }
}
// where TestData() hits the DB and returns corresponding result
```

**Values()** is called multiple places in the same file where this will return by hitting the DB **TestData()** first time and from next calls it will directly return from ViewBag.

Is this is a good approach ?

What are all the alternative approach we have in MVC to handle this scenario ?As DB hit is a costly call we need to use some other techniques.

Thanks

Comment: "Reusing the Data without hitting DB " - that's usually called 'caching'

Answer (score 1):

You could either keep your data in session like this:

```
Session['*your session key*'] = TestData();
```

And then retrieve it like this:

```
var myData = Session['*your session key*'] as YourObject //cast it to an object if you need to.
```

Or you could use caching:

```
System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] = TestData
```

And retrieving:

```
var myData =System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] as YourObject
```

Answer (score 0):

That code should ensure that you only touch the database the first time the method is invoked. 
If the same data is used on multiple pages you could also have a lot at the Cache- or Session class.

Answer (score 0):

If size of the data retrieved from database is not very big then you can use [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Otherwise you can store data in [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have the options to keep the data like Session, Cache.

Answer (score 0):

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 60)] // Caches for 60 seconds
private List<string> Values()
{
    if (ViewBag.Sample == null)
    {
        ViewBag.Sample = TestData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC Model Binder

[See Sample code](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/05/05/iterating-on-an-asp-net-mvc-model-binder.aspx)